# Android: How to put a resources string to SQLite DB onCreate method?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Good day.

I need to put a default string values from resources in my database. I found that I should use a method getResources().getString(R.string.value) but this method requires a Context class.

So, how can I put a data in onCreate() method of a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, you need to pass context.

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper{
    private Context context;
    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String yourString = context.getResources().getString(R.string.value);
        //do what ever you like with your string.
    }
}
```